# How to set goal seek value by a input box?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file where I have to run the goal seek vba to achieve a certain number. But each time I need to change the goal seeking number manually if I run this in other cell. Is there any way of popping up a input box where i can put the required number and then the macro will run to accomplish the operation?

In the code below, goal seek is set to 40. but when i need the goal I have to change the number manually. i am expecting some extension that will require a goal seeking number each time I run the macro. Any idea please ?

```
'
' Run_DIO Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'

    ActiveCell.GoalSeek Goal:=40, ChangingCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(-4, -1).Range( _
        "A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-3, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(4, 2).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure... just add a variable:

```
Dim iGoal As Integer
iGoal = InputBox("Enter Goal")
ActiveCell.GoalSeek Goal:=iGoal, ChangingCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(-4, -1).Range( _
    "A1")
```

Just hope they enter a number or you will get an error.

if you have it in a loop, get the input before the loop starts:

```
Dim iGoal As Integer
iGoal = InputBox("Enter Goal")

' code to start loop goes here

ActiveCell.GoalSeek Goal:=iGoal, ChangingCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(-4, -1).Range( "A1")

' also the rest of the code you want to loop goes here

' code to end loop goes here
```

Comment: at first thanks for your valuable input. After posting, I almost reached there. but the main problem i am facing, is when i need to repeat this for almost 200 cell. That means, i need to give input for 200 times. Actually, I want to run the code setting the goal for once and it will continue till the relative reference found.

Comment: Actually, I want to run the code setting the goal for once and it will continue till the relative reference found. Actually i need to run this for a range with a same goal .

Comment: Your code shows no loop... so if you have a loop, just put the input box outside of the loop... i'll update the answer

Comment: If your problem is more than what you originally specified, then you will want to ask a new question.

Comment: I got your point, you are right but but I am not a pro coder. The code can be applied for a single cell. but I am trying to run the code for 5 cells i.e. C10:G10. And on that time i need to give input for 5 time whereas I am trying to give input for once for the total range.